# How to create an array from list in file

Tags: php, arrays, file

I have a text file `countries.txt` with a list of all countries:

```
1. Australia
2. Austria
3. Belgium
4. US
```

I want to create an array in `country_handler.php` like this:

```
$countries = array(
     '1'=>'Australia',
     '2'=>'Austria',
     '3'=>'Belgium',
     '4'=>'US'
);
```

How to do that?

Answer (score 1):

Better you can use this in a function like below - then just called this function from any where

`function getCountryList()
    {
        return array(
          '1'=>'Australia',
          '2'=>'Austria',
          '3'=>'Belgium',
          '4'=>'US'
        );
    }`

Comment: Thank you for your effort, but there are 250+ countries in my txt file, and it is hard to retype it again. I also have a 250+ txt files with cities for every country and hard coding would be time consuming.

Comment: i feel better you store this data in db table.its too complex to maintain using array with different file.

Comment: I have been thinking about using DB for countries, and it would be easy. The problem is how to store cities in DB. There would be 25000 entries in DB. I had two options: 1. for every country one table (pros:easy to maintain, cons:250 tables and 250 queries to get all cities). 2. all cities in one table (pros:easy to get, cons:hard to maintain)

Comment: yes like this ..in **country** table here you store all country list.then in other table name **city** store the all data using  country table foreign key.
first time its too pain for you but its works lifetime for you :)

Answer (score 0):

```
$data = file_get_contents('countries.txt');
$countries = explode(PHP_EOL, $data);
```

Comment: That was a fast answer! :) Thank you

Comment: Doesn't do anything with keys. PHP's `EOL` might not be the same as the file's.

Answer (score 0):

```
$file = file('countries.txt');

$countries = array();

foreach ($file as $line) {
    @list ($index, $country) = explode('.', $line);
    $countries[trim($index)] = trim($country);
}

print_r($countries);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$lines = file('countries.txt');

$newArr = array();
foreach ($lines as $line) {
    $erg = preg_split('/\.\s+/', $line);
    $newArr[$erg[0]] = $erg[1];  
}
var_dump($newArr);
```

Comment: Does it work for `The Netherlands` and `Czech Republic` as well?

Comment: Yes, because of the "."

Answer (score 0):

Luckily (sometimes) regex doesn't include newlines in the `.`, so you can do this:

```
$contents = file_get_contents('countries.txt');
preg_match_all('#(\d+)\.\s+(.+)#', $contents, $matches);
print_r($matches);
```

The regex means:

- `(\d+)` -- a number (save this)
- `\.` -- a literal dot
- `\s+` -- white space
- `(.+)` -- any character except `\n` or `\r` (end-of-line) (save this)

Which results in:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1. Australia
            [1] => 2. Austria
            [2] => 3. Belgium
            [3] => 4. US
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => 1
            [1] => 2
            [2] => 3
            [3] => 4
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [0] => Australia
            [1] => Austria
            [2] => Belgium
            [3] => US
        )

)
```

and I'm sure from `[1]` and `[2]` you can make the keyed array you need.

`array_combine` to the easy rescue:

```
$countries = array_combine($matches[1], $matches[2]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
<?php
    $data = file_get_contents('countries.txt');
    $countries = explode(PHP_EOL,$data);               
    $cnt = 1;
    foreach($countries as $val) {
      if($val <>"") {
         $res[$cnt] = strstr(trim($val), ' ');
         $cnt++;
      }
    }
    print_r($res);
    ?>
```